# Retrieve Specific Data/Value From Database 1 Line PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just wondering how I can retrieve a specific value (only 1 thing will be returned) from a database using php.

My query is

```
mysql_query("SELECT balance FROM users WHERE username = '". $this->username . "'")
```

I'm just looking for it to retrieve the data from that row so I can save it directory into a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, you can limit the number of results using LIMIT:

```
mysql_query("SELECT balance FROM users WHERE username = '". $this->username . "' LIMIT 1")
```

Comment: You can get more information on the LIMIT clause here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html